# Белок коагулируется  или коагулирует?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно : белок коагулируется  или коагулирует?

Answer (score 1):

Коагулировать- подвергать коагуляции(свёртыванию), коагулироваться-подвергаться коагуляции.
Белок подвергается коагуляции, значит,коагулируется.